# jquery .load() does not get variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        $("body").load(href);
    });
});
```

But it does not work. Nothing loads. The only thing that works is `e.preventdefault()`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: how about putting the e.preventDefault() after the "load"? Also, do you see anything happening on the server where "href" is pointing?

Comment: Why would you do this with XmlHttpRequest? `a` elements already do this properly.

Comment: @ElGuapo: Where does `href` point? It's an undefined variable. :)

Comment: I assumed (probably poorly) that there was an actual <a href=""> somewhere that wasn't mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("body").load(href);
```

Should be:

```
$("body").load(url);
```

Or you could do away with the variable completely:

```
$("body").load(this.href);
```

Comment: $("body").load(this.href); is the cleanest way!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the **$** before the `(this).attr('href');` and also use the value url for your load function call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            url = $(this).attr('href');
            $("body").load(url);
    });
});
```

Comment: You could just use this.href rather than $(this).attr('href') to save on creating another jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned href attr to variable called url, then tried to use href as a variable.

Not good:

```
url = $(this).attr('href');    
$("body").load(href);
```

Good:

```
url = $(this).attr('href');    
$("body").load(url);
```